# How to run sudo commands in terraform?

Tags: sudo, provisioning, terraform

My question is similar to this git hub post, but unfortunately it is unsolved:

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/550

I want a simple way to give sudo privileges to the commands run in the `provisioner "remote-exec" { }` block of my terraform scripts.

I am coming from an ansible background that has the `sudo: yes` option that allows any commands ansible runs to run commands with sudo privileges when using the `--ask-sudo-pass` optional in my ansible-playbook run commands.  I would like to do something like that in the `provisioner "remote-exec"` block of my terraform script.

Here is the `provisioner "remote-exec"` block I want to run:

```
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo apt-get update",
      "sudo apt-get install -y curl"
    ]
  }
```

When I run this in my `terraform apply` I see the following lines appear in the output of this command:

```
openstack_compute_instance_v2.test.0 (remote-exec): [sudo] password for myUserName:
openstack_compute_instance_v2.test.1 (remote-exec): [sudo] password for myUserName:
openstack_compute_instance_v2.test.2 (remote-exec): [sudo] password for myUserName:
```

Then it just gives me an infinite number of these:

```
openstack_compute_instance_v2.test.0: Still creating... 
openstack_compute_instance_v2.test.1: Still creating... 
openstack_compute_instance_v2.test.2: Still creating...
```

So how do I fix this and let terraform run sudo commands?

**Note:** The connection for my `provisioner "remote-exec"` block cannot be root, so even though that would be a simple solution its not what I can use.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer was to use the following syntax in my first sudo command:

```
"echo yourPW | sudo -S someCommand"
```

This bypasses the sudo password prompt and enters the password directly into the command.  I already had my sudo password as a variable `"${var.pw}"` so running my sudo commands was the simple matter of changing my first command to:

```
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "echo ${var.pw} | sudo -S apt-get update",
      "sudo apt-get install -y curl"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Won't this print passwords to the log? Also, it seems risky that you expect the second `sudo` to not ask for password because the first run caches it.

Comment: It might. Honestly I haven't touched terraform in years.  If you have a better solution, post it!

Answer (score 4):

In case of EC2 instance, its difficult to handle that with password. I just a gave try to below solution and it worked.

Step 1 : Put all of your commands in script.sh file in your current workspace/working directory

Step 2 : Instead of **inline** argument, use script argument and simply include below lines of code in resource block.

```
provisioner "file" {
    source      = "script.sh"
    destination = "/tmp/script.sh"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "chmod +x /tmp/script.sh",
      "sudo /tmp/script.sh args",
    ]
  }
```

With this solution, terraform will copy the script.sh containing all the shell commands need to be executed at /tmp location of server and it will execute the file with sudo permissions.Below is the reference link.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/remote-exec.html

Comment: perfect, works like a ninja !

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
echo ${var.pw} | sudo -S -k apt-get update
```

`-k` means to ignore cached credentials to force sudo to always ask. This is for consistent behavior.

https://superuser.com/q/67765

Comment: I really wanted to comment on Alex Cohen's answer but can't since I'm a new member and don't have 50 reputation, so posting this separate.

Comment: Nope. Adding an answer is the appropriate way, since you have a different solution.